# Where is the Region labelled East US 2 in Azure?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I can't find any information on this. Where is this Region? I understand that the **East US** region is in Virginia but I'm specifically asking about the **East US 2** region.

[image: Screenshot of US East 2 in the Azure Management Portal]

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Azure_Services_Platform#Datacenters

Comment: @MattBall Thanks for that link but it doesn't tell me where **East US 2** is. **East US** is Virginia. I think you simply ignored my question, assumed it was stupid, and voted to close it. :-/ Please try harder, next time...

Comment: I suspect this may have been a temporary glitch. I checked and do not see an East US 2 option, and I checked against both my MSDN subscription and my Internal Microsoft subscription. Do you still see East US 2?

Comment: There is a US East 2 now. http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/regions/#services

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[Azure Regions](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/regions/):

```
AZURE REGION        LOCATION
Central US          Iowa
East US             Virginia
East US 2           Virginia
US Gov Iowa         Iowa
US Gov Virginia     Virginia
North Central US    Illinois
South Central US    Texas
West US             California
North Europe        Ireland
West Europe         Netherlands
East Asia           Hong Kong
Southeast Asia      Singapore
Japan East          Saitama Prefecture
Japan West          Osaka Prefecture
Brazil South        Sao Paulo State
Australia East      New South Wales
Australia Southeast Victoria
```

*At the time question was asked, there wasn't an "East US 2". It was shown due to a bug and was fixed.*

Comment: Thank you for being helpful. Apparently that was hard to ask for until you came along. I appreciate it.

Comment: I just confirmed this as well, as I suspected when I commented earlier. But @Jaxidian - no need to get an attitude at people here who volunteer their time, accusing them of ignoring your questions and telling them to try harder next time, especially when this was a temporary glitch that nobody else has seen and that nobody else but someone at Microsoft could have even looked into.

Comment: There is now a East US 2, so this answer is invalid.
http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/general-availability-microsoft-azure-us-central-and-us-east-2-regions/

Comment: It appears this answer has been updated and is again correct with both the now-current information and a link to the source in case it changes. (Not that I expect the data center to move overnight.)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that you will ever find an official answer to this question. Apart from competitive reasons (where people look at satellite images to see how 'big' a datacentre is), there are also security reasons why, as customers, we want this kept a secret. You wouldn't want, for example, datacentre staff being followed home and coerced into handing over data (not that they could anyway). I'm not sure exactly how Microsoft does it, but Amazon locates availability zones (different datacentres in the same region) reasonably close (10s of miles) so that they have separate power and other dependencies/risks, but are close enough for dedicated bandwidth between the datacentres to be affordable. So you will seldom notice a significant performance difference between two datacentres in a single region.

If you are planning something nefarious, you are going to have to ask somewhere else. If you want to know in order to find out which datacentre is 'closer' to you for application performance reasons, then you just need to measure latency. Physical location is irrelevant. If the geographically furthest location has the lowest latency, then you will still choose it. It is easy to measure latency with web apps, and [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlazure/archive/2010/05/27/10016392.aspx) describes how you can use SQL statistics to measure latency to SQL Azure. Ultimately, the choice of datacentre location should be based on where your customers are, not your office, and as far as customers are concerned, a location fidelity of a hundred miles will make absolutely no difference.

Comment: I was simply wanting to know if it was north or south of **US East** / Virginia. I'm not planning any terrorist attacks on empty data centers. o.O